# I moved my folder from lib to /app in a rails 6, I can't seem to instantiate an object still because of load path issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a new rails 6 application and in the lib folder I had this:

/lib/some_app_name/stripe/subscription/subscription_service.rb

```
module Someappname # Someappname is also in my application.rb 
  module Stripe
    class SubscriptionService
      def initialize(a)
        @a = a
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I then moved the 'some_app_name' folder to:

/app/some_app_name/stripe/subscription_service.rb

I read that anything inside of /app will be autoloaded and reloaded so I moved in here.  It wasn't working in /lib also.

In my home_controller.rb I tried this:

```
ss = Someappname::Stripe::SubscriptionService.new("a")
```

I get an error saying:

> uninitialized constant Someappname::Stripe::SubscriptionService

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, does your error trace refer to zeitwerk?

Comment: @jvillian no it didn't.  is there a way using rails c I can somehow debug this further?

Comment: @Blankman Sir, did you try restarting the console?

Comment: Not sure. Might help if you include full error trace in your question

Comment: @RajdeepSingh yes I have restarted, no change.

Comment: @Blankman Please check my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect it's `spring`, try this

```
bin/spring stop
```

And then start `rails console`, stopping Spring will force `Rails` to load your app fresh

**Also,**

if the name of your module is `Someappname`, then the directory name should be `app/someappname` and not `some_app_name`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did spring stop, but no change, does it start back up with 'rails s'?

Comment: @Blankman if the name of your module is Someappname, then the directory name should be app/someappname and not some_app_name, can you please try fixing it

Comment: that was the problem, the folder name was 'some_app_name'.  I wanted the module name to be 'SomeAppName' but it only works if I have 'Someappname'.  Is there a way to change this?  It just looks strange...

Comment: @Blankman Ofcourse, change the module name to `SomeAppName`, I don't think it would cause any issue?

Comment: @Blankman You just need to call it like this after the name change, `SomeAppName::Stripe::SubscriptionService.new("a")`

Answer (score 6):

Rails does auto-load everything under `/app`, but there's a caveat. First level of directories is not becoming a part of module name. That's why you can have `class User` in `/app/models/user.rb` (and not `class Models::User`).

Solution: place your code into *some* folder under `/app`. I usually call it `/app/lib` or `/app/custom` or something like that.

```
/app/custom/some_app_name/stripe/subscription/subscription_service.rb
```

(and yes, make sure that names in your filepath correctly represent names in your module path. You can't have directory `some_app_name` for module `Someappname`, but you can for `SomeAppName`)