# Cannot auto-load class in Rails6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zeitwerk

I want to add custom class to app folder into clean Rails 6 project, ruby 2.7.0.
According to  Zeitwerk documentation it should auto-load all paths under app directory.

```
app/custom/car.rb
class Car
  def self.print
    print 'Car'
  end  
end
```

I'm getting error in a rails console

```
2.7.0 :001 > Car.print
NameError (uninitialized constant Car)
```

What is wrong?

Note: when I put car.rb to app/models it works fine, but not when it's inside app/custom  directory

Comment: Have you looked into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58681673/i-moved-my-folder-from-lib-to-app-in-a-rails-6-i-cant-seem-to-instantiate-an?

Comment: All the directories under `app` should load automatically.  Try `spring stop` and restart the `rails serer`

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is likely not with the Zeitwerk loader, but with the Spring preloader that runs by default - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths notes that "By default, the autoload paths of an application consist of all the subdirectories of app that exist when the application boots"

That "when the application **boots**" note is very important - with spring in play, if you add a folder to `/app` and spring is already running, you'll have to restart the spring preloader to reboot the app in the background so Zeitwerk will pick it up.

`bundle exec spring status` will show you the status of the spring preloader, and you can use `bundle exec spring stop` to stop it and force it to reload the next time you run a command that would use it like `rails console`